# Why does the LED light in the laundry room glow when the garage light is switched on?

Tags: led

I recently installed an LED light in the laundry room. I only touched the ceiling installation (B to B, G to G, W to W.) It is a dual light switch - one to the garage, one to the laundry room. When I turn on garage light, the LED light glows even though the laundry room switch is off. The other side of the laundry room has a dual switch to the kitchen. When I turn on the kitchen light, the LED does not glow. Otherwise, all works fine with all lights switching.

Why does the LED light in the laundry room glow  when the garage light is switched on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Why does the LED light in the laundry room glow when the garage light
> is switched on?*

Quite possibly due to wiring capacitance. If the garage light wires run along side the laundry room light wiring then, there could be a few nano farads of coupling and, this can cause efficient LED lights to glow a bit.

I'm presuming here that the laundry lamp doesn't go the full brightness here.

Comment: Laundry lamp does not go full bright. Any way to fix or just live with it? Thanks Andy!

Comment: Space the cables apart if you have access to them is my best guess. if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: @Buck A parallel load, like a small incandescent bulb, on the same (affected, weakly lit) circuit will likely do the job.